# accessing old data from syslog

Tags: debian, grep, syslog

I look after various MySQL DB's which we have recently moved to Linux servers (from Windows). They run fine and everything is good. However, this morning i needed to check the error logs, but these are now written to `/var/log/syslog`.

My SysAdmin is off today, and I can't for the life of me see how to read this data.

I can get the latest data fine using

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

But how do I access data from 1:00 am today? or from yesterday for that matter.

I tried:

```
grep mysqld /var/log/syslog | less
```

but that shows me data from 6am onwards

I then tried

```
grep '^Nov  4 01' /var/log/syslog | less
```

but that showed me nothing but a long list of ^

Comment: If `head /var/log/syslog` gives you dates that aren't early enough, maybe old logfiles have been rotated away. Are there any other `syslog*` files in `/var/log` (that you have access to)?

Comment: you  were spot on, it looks like the logs got rotated just after 6am this morning, so the one I wanted was `/var/log/syslog.1`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz may as well make that into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Syslog gets [rotated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation) on a regular basis. The result looks like this:

```bash
$ ls /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog  /var/log/syslog.1  ...  /var/log/syslog.7.gz
```

To grep the pattern "mysqld" in regular and rotated syslog files use zgrep, that is capable of grepping uncompressed and compressed files:

```bash
$ zgrep mysqld /var/log/syslog* | less
```

To grep for lines that contain "mysql" and a specific date, use the -E switch, that enables extended [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```bash
$ zgrep -E 'Nov  4 01.+mysqld' /var/log/syslog* | less
```